# SQL Select details with a totals column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

if I have this table

```
PID     Phase   CtrlDollars       ActualDollars
-----------------------------------------------
1        A          25.00              50.00
1        B          10.00              23.00
1        c          2.00               14.00
2        A          24.00              24.00
2        B          10.00              20.00
```

How can I write a select to give me a

```
Total for the Actual Dollars for each PID (TotalActDollsForPID)
```

but still show details (and this is what the cust wants)

```
PID     Phase    CtrlDollars      ActualDollars    TotalActDollsForPID
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1        A          25.00              50.00             87.00
1        B          10.00              23.00             87.00
1        c          2.00               14.00             87.00
2        A          24.00              24.00             44.00
2        B          10.00              20.00             44.00
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT p.PID, 
       p.PHASE, 
       p.CtrlDollars, 
       p.ActualDollars, 
       t.TotalActDollsForPID
FROM mytable p
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT PID, 
            SUM(ActualDollars) AS TotalActDollsForPID 
     FROM mytable GROUP BY PID) AS t
ON t.PID = p.PID
```

Comment: Like a BOSS --- Thanks mlinth!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a SQL Server 2005+, you can use [the `OVER()` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
SELECT PID,
    Phase,
    CtrlDollars,
    ActualDollars,
    SUM(ActualDollars) OVER(PARTITION BY PID) AS "TotalActDollsForPID"
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, in addition to using a subquery and a window function is to use `apply`:

```
SELECT
    PID,
    Phase,
    CtrlDollars,
    ActualDollars,
    TotalActDollsForPID 
FROM Table1 t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT 
        SUM(actualdollars) AS TotalActDollsForPID 
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE PID = t.PID 
    GROUP BY pid
) oa
```

It might give better performance (or not, ymmv).